# VSCode Creating Empty File With Same Name

Tags: c++, file

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN6Vi.png) I'm Having an issue with my vscode creating an empty file alongside my main cpp file.

For example:
If i create "helloworld.cpp".
Vscode will also create an empty file named "helloworld."

When i try to open this file i get the mesasge saying "The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding."

I've heard from others the it maybe a user snippet or a file template issue but have no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: That is probably the executable produced when you compile your `.cpp` file. Remember you can not run a cpp file, instead you compile and link it first to create an executable that can be run. This question explains what happens: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: C++ doesn't run from the .cpp file. The .cpp file has to be compiled to an executable.

Comment: The actual build command should be visible on the  VSCode terminal. And that should help explain the behavior that you see.